# Is there a way to calculate the indices generated by nested for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, for-loop

I'm currently thinking about how to store frequently accessed data. It is meant to be stored in an array and is currently generated the following way.

```
public static void generateData() {

    int index = 0;
    for(int a1 = 0; a1 < 52; a1++) {
        for(int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < 52; a2++) {
            for(int a3 = a2 + 1; a3 < 52; a3++) {
                for(int a4 = a3 + 1; a4 < 52; a4++) {
                    for(int a5 = a4 + 1; a5 < 52; a5++) {
                        for(int a6 = a5 + 1; a6 < 52; a6++) {
                            for(int a7 = a6 + 1; a7 < 52; a7++) {
                                data[index++] = compute(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my issue is now to quickly access the computed data using the a1 to a7 parameters. The only approach I could think of is to iterate similar as during iteration time until the parameters are the same, like this

```
public static int getIndex(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int a1 = 0; a1 < 52; a1++) {
        for(int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < 52; a2++) {
            for(int a3 = a2 + 1; a3 < 52; a3++) {
                for(int a4 = a3 + 1; a4 < 52; a4++) {
                    for(int a5 = a4 + 1; a5 < 52; a5++) {
                        for(int a6 = a5 + 1; a6 < 52; a6++) {
                            for(int a7 = a6 + 1; a7 < 52; a7++) {

                                if(a1 == i1 && a2 == i2 && a3 == i3 && a4 == i4 && a5 == i5 && a6 == i6 && a7 == i7) {
                                    return index;
                                } else {
                                    index++;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

However this approach only runs at linear time, which isn't fast enough considering the amount of data. Because of that I was wondering if there is any way to calculate the index in constant or logarithmic time.
As my question might seem quite vague. I'm storing all possible outcomes of each possible `Texas hold'em` hand to do some further testing.

Comment: this is more of a math question than a programming question

Comment: Since data is sorted so you might want to use binary search for each a1, a2,..., a7 value, and then calculate the index. ex: index = founded index of a1 * founded index of a2 * founded index of a3 ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case `index` can be treated as a number in [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), where loop variables `a1`...`a7` are the digits of this number.

[image: formula of index]

Here is a function that calculates index from given loop variables.

```
public static int getIndex(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6, int a7) {
    return 133784559 - (C7[a1] + C6[a2] + C5[a3] + C4[a4] + C3[a5] + C2[a6] + (51 - a7));
}

static final int[] C2 = Ck(2), C3 = Ck(3), C4 = Ck(4), C5 = Ck(5), C6 = Ck(6), C7 = Ck(7);

// Creates a cache of C(51-i, k) for 0 <= i < 52
static int[] Ck(int k) {
    int[] result = new int[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        result[i] = (int) C(51 - i, k);
    }
    return result;
}

// Computes binomial coefficient C(n, k)
static long C(int n, int k) {
    long C = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        C = C * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    return C;
}
```

`getIndex` method is pretty fast and requires only about 1K of extra static memory.

Comment: Does exactly what I wanted. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could consider storing the parameters as a string key in a map to the index you need. So you could declare `Map<String,Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();` in your class somewhere.

Then in your generateData method you could store the parameters as one big string key.

```
    indexMap.put(Integer.toString(a1)+Integer.toString(a2)+ ... +
    Integer.toString(a7),index);
```

Just make sure you store the index before you increment it. This would allow you to then do

```
    return indexMap.get(Integer.toString(a1)+Integer.toString(a2)+ ... +
    Integer.toString(a7));
```

You should do error checking for a key not found error, but this will allow you to retrieve the index you want much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `HashMap` to keep `a1..a7 -> compute value`, as I'm not sure if there is an efficient algo to retrieve index from `a1 ... a7` in reasonable time. But I would use `Long` as Map key and construct it in the next way

```
long key = (((((a1 * 100L + a2) * 100 + a3) * 100 + a4) * 100 + a5) * 100 + a6) * 100 + a7
```

or as a function

```
public static long getKey(int ... array) {
    if (array.length != 7) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    long value = 0;
    for (int item : array) {
        value = value * 100 + item;
    }
    return value;
}
```

This should make search, key generation and space consumption efficient (Map will contain 133784560 entries).

**Note**, that `a1` is multiplied by `100L`, otherwise result will be incorrect, as it doesn't fit Integer range.

Comment: This is an awful solution since it requires gigabytes of heap memory just to compute an index from 7 integers.